# How to render component with *ngIf else

Tags: javascript, angular

I am new to angular and I am writing dummy app to teach myself angular.
My idea was to have 2 inputs where player1 and player2 write down their names. When they press the button game starts and shows their names and health.

I am doing that with *ngIf else, but when I click the button to change boolean nothing is shown.

What is the problem and is there a better way to do that?

app.component.html

```
<p>This will not change!</p>
<ng-template *ngIf="startGame;
  else noStart">
  <p> Render other components for health and names. Did game start: {{startGame}}</p>
</ng-template>
<ng-template #noStart>
  <h1> Input player names to start the game!</h1>
  <input [(ngModel)]="player1">
  <br>
  <input [(ngModel)]="player2">
  <br>
  <button (click)="onStartGame()">Start</button>
</ng-template>
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  startGame: boolean = false;
  player1: string = '';
  player2: string = '';
  username = '';

  setPlayer1(event) {
    this.player1 = event.target.value;
  }

  setPlayer2(event) {
    this.player2 = event.target.value;
  }

  onStartGame() {
    if(this.player1 !== '' && this.player2 !== '')
      this.startGame = true;
  }
}
```

I want to render other component or HTML if boolean changes in if statment.

Comment: Change the ng-template with the ngIf into an ng-container

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`ng-template`](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#the-ng-template) just create a template and which won't show by default, use [`ng-container`](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#ng-container-to-the-rescue) for that purpose which helps to group and 
 add multiple elements to DOM.

```
<p>This will not change!</p>
<ng-container *ngIf="startGame;
  else noStart">
  <p> Render other components for health and names. Did game start: {{startGame}}</p>
</ng-container>
<ng-template #noStart>
  <h1> Input player names to start the game!</h1>
  <input [(ngModel)]="player1">
  <br>
  <input [(ngModel)]="player2">
  <br>
  <button (click)="onStartGame()">Start</button>
</ng-template>
```

---

You can event use [`*ngIf`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf) directive with the `p` tag since there is only one element(`p` tag) and use  [`ng-container`](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#ng-container-to-the-rescue) whenever you want to group multiple elements.

```
<p>This will not change!</p>
<p *ngIf="startGame;
  else noStart"> Render other components for health and names. Did game start: {{startGame}}</p>
<ng-template #noStart>
  <h1> Input player names to start the game!</h1>
  <input [(ngModel)]="player1">
  <br>
  <input [(ngModel)]="player2">
  <br>
  <button (click)="onStartGame()">Start</button>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: God bless you. ty :)

Answer (score -1):

Change *ngIf and write [ngIf] but is not recommendable

Comment: You could do better to explain the answer, if this is indeed it. You also mention the above is not recommended, so would be worth explaining why this is the case.